# How to get reference collection data in mongoose using lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

## Lookup:

```
const course = await mongoose.model('Course').aggregate()
    .match({ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) })
    .lookup({
        from: 'User',
        foreignField: '_id',
        localField: 'userId',
        as: 'user'
    })
```

## Course schema:

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
}, { strict: false });
```

## Expected output:

```
{
    "course": [
        {
            "_id": "64b000c085e9b1aec5975249",
            "title": "test",
            "userId": "64affc47d81a4bfba92b5540",
            "user": [], // data here should be present but empty why?
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I get user data in the above output?

## Works using populate:

```
const course = await mongoose.model('Course')
            .find({ _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) })
            .populate('userId').exec();
```

But how to achieve this using aggregation pipeline?

Comment: What is `userId`? Separately, is there a reason you're using aggregation for this? I'm pretty sure with Mongoose you can use the `.populate()` functionality

Comment: @user20042973 userId is the reference. Updated the question. I am used to using aggregation stages instead of population.

Answer (score 1):

The collection name is `users`, not `User`. See [option: collection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection)

> Mongoose by default produces a collection name by passing the model name to the `utils.toCollectionName` method. This method pluralizes the name.

Let's see the `utils.toCollectionName` method:

```
exports.toCollectionName = function(name, pluralize) {
  if (name === 'system.profile') {
    return name;
  }
  if (name === 'system.indexes') {
    return name;
  }
  if (typeof pluralize === 'function') {
    return pluralize(name);
  }
  return name;
};

function pluralize(str) {
  let found;
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  if (!~uncountables.indexOf(str)) {
    found = rules.filter(function(rule) {
      return str.match(rule[0]);
    });
    if (found[0]) {
      return str.replace(found[0][0], found[0][1]);
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

See [full source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/eeefdd2b1a5cb9d3b59a264d6e9609756763d70d/lib/helpers/pluralize.js#L83)

As you can see, the model name `'User'` will be converted to the collection name `"users"`. So it should be `from: "users"`, not `from: "User"` in `lookup()` method.

The `localField` and `foreignField` are wrong. The `localField` is the field in the local collection which is `cources`. The `foreignField` is the field in the foreign collection which is `users`.

- `from: <foreign collection>`
- `localField: <field from local collection's documents>`,
- `foreignField: <field from foreign collection's documents>`

A working example:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: String,
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
        },
    },
    { strict: false },
);
const Course = mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        // seed
        const [u1] = await User.create([{ name: 'user-a' }]);
        const [c] = await Course.create([{ title: 'course a', userId: u1 }]);

        const r = await Course.aggregate()
            .match({ _id: c?._id })
            .lookup({
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'userId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user',
            });

        console.log(util.inspect(r, false, null));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```
7.3.2
Mongoose: users.insertOne({ name: 'user-a', _id: ObjectId("64b0e2768c75418f819995af"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: courses.insertOne({ title: 'course a', userId: ObjectId("64b0e2768c75418f819995af"), _id: ObjectId("64b0e2778c75418f819995b1"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: courses.aggregate([ { '$match': { _id: new ObjectId("64b0e2778c75418f819995b1") } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'userId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'user' } }], {})
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64b0e2778c75418f819995b1"),
    title: 'course a',
    userId: new ObjectId("64b0e2768c75418f819995af"),
    __v: 0,
    user: [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("64b0e2768c75418f819995af"),
        name: 'user-a',
        __v: 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `userId` in `Course` collection is objectId instead of plain String
you can aggregate result by following query,

```
db.Course.aggregate([{$match:{_id:ObjectId("yourId")}}
,{$lookup:{
  from: 'User',
  localField: 'userId',
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: 'users'
}}])
```

if you have userId as plain String you need to use `$addFields` to convert your string id to ObjectId.

```
db.Course.aggregate([{$match:{_id:ObjectId("yourId")}}
,{$addFields:{'userId':{"$toObjectId":"$userId"}}}
,{$lookup:{
  from: 'User',
  localField: 'userId',
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: 'users'
}}])
```